# Why do newer software ignore Windows' (or operative system's) UI scheme? New software ignoring windows look and feel and UI color theme

Tags: windows, colors, themes, look-and-feel, color-scheme

I don't know if this question belongs here in Stack Overflow. It may go in other page but not sure where.

Myself having an eye dissease I lost a lot of sight over the years though I always have had bad sight.
I came across to a point where I have to use high contrast to see things properly in a computer which is crappy but it is how it is.

Until a little time before, software used to have the same colour scheme as the operative system on windows and if I used a high contrast theme, the software respected the same theme and I had no problem at all cause the software was also in that same looking theme.

However lately programs tend to follow a tencency where the theme goes independent from the windows UI and doesnt change the look and feel no matter what windows theme I use. I see this happening even more a more day by day with newer software and older software.
Software that releases updates which I had no problems with before, are updating to use an independent look and feel from the operative system's. I see this in antivirus, and other various coding and creative programs. And a lot of those probrams don't even have an option for customizing the UI.

I see a mayor step backwards in regards of accessibility in computer software.
High software was designed for eye sight issues and limiting software to not respect this is a problem.

I have more and more problems with this as time passes cause it's becomeing a rule and I can see myself having not to work as a programmer cause of this.

I just want someone to explain me why this is. I'm thinking about moving my profession cause it's frustrating. I was tought that software and web was to be made thinking in everyone and as time goes on i see more problems working on a computer, just because software devs are following a tendency.
Most programs want to look like the Material theme.

Comment: *"I don't know if this question belongs here in Stack Overflow."* - No, it doesn't. This is not a programming problem. But anyway, if you feel that this is an issue, send a kind letter to [The Qt Company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Qt_Company) kindly asking them to stop writing a shitty framework, that allows for all the alpha transparency you want, and start writing one, that's usable. By everyone. Or write to the software vendors and ask them to stop using Qt.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have the knowlegde to write a framework, If I could do something to make it more universal, believe me that I would do it.

Comment: I wasn't asking you to write a framework. I was asking you to ask **them** to make it suck less, because you have made a pretty good case, why it does.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm not sure what and how to say them and trying not to be rude cause I don't want to be rude cause I guess it's a hard work what they do, but I just wonder if more people in my same situation feels the way I do about this now. I think I'll be thinking something to write to them.